# Scrollable multi-nested Flexbox with both parent and children scrollable

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am facing trouble while trying to implement one of design use-case (I am no designer/ui-developer).

I need to make a **parent div *horizontally* scrollable**, while its **children as *vertically* scrollable**. There can be n-number of children.

I am trying to use `flex` but it's not suiting the requirement. No existing answer on SO is having what I need. Any help would be appreciated.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQxOER

```css
#main-container {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#contexts-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 600px;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 2500px;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#context-container {
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">

  <div id="some-child">
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
    text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
    text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
    text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
  </div>

  <div id="contexts-container" class="border-top border-light">

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer De scription. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the inner scroll horizontally, you need to give the `context-div`s a min-width that will be larger than the container.

To make the context divs scroll, just give them a height.

Please also note - ids should be unique so I would change the context div id to a class

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#main-container {
  width: 800px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#contexts-container {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
}

#contexts-container>div {
  padding: 20px;
  min-width: 500px;      /* can be what you want */
  height: 400px;         /* can be what you want */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">

  <div id="some-child">
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
    text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
    text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some
    text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
    Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
  </div>

  <div id="contexts-container" class="border-top border-light">
    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer De scription. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="context-container" class="">
      <h2>Context Title</h2>

      <div class="answers-container" class="">
        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="answer-container">
          <h3>Answer Title</h3>
          <p>
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
            Answer Description. Answer Description. Answer Description.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's working like a charm here for sure, but I am still in process of grasping this magic `min-width` did. (I am a backend developer primarily). And `id`s are of course different. It's running in a backend rendered loop having dynamic ids.

Comment: @Sachin flex will recalculate the inner divs to make them fit, just giving the min width means that they will be forced onto one line and they will exceed the width of the parent rather than just fitting.  It basically moves the width from the parent to the child - allowing the parent not to be 2500px and therefore overflow on the x

Comment: Thanks. I am kinda getting the relation between `min-width` with `overflow` with respect to parent. When it comes to dynamic calculation and not knowing the actual width, `min-width` is the parameter which gives some basis for overall calculation and thereby need for `overflow`.

Comment: unfortunately with flex - unless the min-width is supplied, all the children will be forced into the available space.  If you had no width set - how would the children know how wide to be and when to wrap (their text in order to give them vertical scroll)

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense as well. Otherwise it would be ambiguity/uncertainty around. Got you. Thanks :)